# jQuery AJAX refresh doesn't work on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, ajax

So I've set up a Node.js Server and I'm using the EJS template Engine.
I have a site where I refresh 3 spans with jQuery's AJAX, the data that has to be filled into these spans comes from a json file which is constantly updated from the Server. I use Ratchet as a Front-End Framework.

On my Computer everything works like it should. But my problem is that on my iPhone (Safari Browser and/or saving to Home Screen) the spans that should get refreshed, simply don't get refreshed (On iPhone, I have to refresh the entire page manually) like they do on my Computer (Win10 64-Bit, Firefox).

If it helps: It's an iPhone 6S

So, what causes this failure? Is it that iOS' Safari simply doesn't support AJAX or is it something else?

Answer (score 0):

Got it, just restarted the entire phone, don't know why but it works how it was supposed to work now!
Sorry for disturbing